# Org Wide Sharing Settings on Sandbox Creation

Tags: sandbox, org-wide-defaults

I have some Apex test methods that check creation of records in the ContactShare object. They work well in the Sandbox orgs that are already created. However, whenever I create a new Sandbox they always fail until I "switch on and off" private security model. Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 4):

Some objects in salesforce are created only when few configurations exist .You are running into similar scenario . ContactShare exists only if you have the private sharing model turned on .

To avoid failure of the test classes your code can check for its existence using the below method

```
Type contactShare = Type.forName('ContactShare');
if(contactShare != null){
    //contact share exists
}
```

**Update**

It looks like record creation fails and switching from private to public and then to private again fixes the test classes .Sounds like a bug at first glance .

Comment: Hey Mohith (hope all is going well at CS, miss you guys). This isn't about the object missing, the object is there, its about the creation of certain records in the actual object itself.

Comment: Ah yes ! I see ok certain types of record will obviously fail because of the public model .The share records sometimes makes sense only on private sharing model. Best way is to add try and catch around record creation and do an error handling .

Comment: It's not even that. So what happens is, I am expecting a certain UserOrGroupId, ContactId combination to be there in the test method. Again, this works in well established sandboxes. However, when I spin up a new one, the test fails. It only begins to work when I switch from Private to Public, and then back to Private.

Comment: I see , sounds like a candidate for salesforce case .I would also take a metadata extract of new sandbox and then extract once you do switch (private to public to private)  and compare them to see what extra gets added .

Comment: Agreed, as for the metadata, it is exactly the same (tracking via Git).